# Method not being called everytime

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I'm working on a poker game at the moment, in which I am just testing out the logic of the game before I begin developing a GUI, and I have noticed that the `Winner()` method isn't being called everytime.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using CardGamev1;

namespace Poker {
    public class Program {
        static Rank rank = new Rank();
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            SetPlayers();
            WriteCards();
            SeeWhoWins();
            Winner();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void SetPlayers() {
            rank.Deal.InitialisePlayers();
            rank.Deal.DealPlayerCards(2);
            rank.Deal.DealTableCards(5);
        }


        static void WriteCards() {
            for (int i = 0; i < rank.Deal.NumberOfPlayers; i++) {
                Console.Write("\nPlayer " + (i + 1) + " Cards:");
                for (int j = 0; j < rank.Deal.Players[i].PlayerCards.Count; j++) {
                    Console.Write("\n\t" + rank.Deal.Players[i].PlayerCards[j].FaceName + " of " + rank.Deal.Players[i].PlayerCards[j].SuitName);
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\nThe Table Cards:");
            for (int i = 0; i < rank.Deal.TableCards.Count; i++) {
                Console.Write("\n\t" + rank.Deal.TableCards[i].FaceName + " of " + rank.Deal.TableCards[i].SuitName);
            }

        }

        static void SeeWhoWins() {
            rank.Deal.AddDataToSortLists();
            rank.DetermineWinner(); 
        }

        static void Winner() {            
            string winningHand = "";
            Console.Write("\n\nThe winner is: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < rank.Winners.Count; i++) {
                winningHand = rank.PlayerHandRank(rank.Deal.Players[rank.Winners[i]].HandRank[0]);
                Console.Write("\nPlayer " + (rank.Winners[i]+1) + " with " + winningHand);
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

It is currently being tested using Console.

My problem is that the game does what it is tended to do at this stage in development but the `Winner()` randomly doesn't call whenever I run the program.

Does anyone know the problem to this.

**Note:** if you need to see more classes, I can edit my question but I felt that it may clutter the question too much.

**Appendix - Rank Class (work in progress)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CardGamev1 {
    public class Rank {
        public Deal Deal = new Deal();
        private int firstValue = 0;
        private int secondValue = 0;
        private int thirdValue = 0;
        private int flushCounter = 1;

        private int straightCounter = 1;
        private int firstConsequtiveNum = 1;
        private int secondConsequtiveNum = 1;
        private int thirdConsequtiveNum = 1;
        private bool highCard = false;
        private bool royalFlush = false;
        private bool straightFlush = false;
        private bool straight = false;
        private bool flush = false;

        private bool nextPair = false;
        private bool finalPair = false;
        private bool twoPair = false;
        private bool pair = false;
        private bool threeKind = false;
        private bool fourKind = false;
        private bool fullHouse = false;

        private List<int> winners = new List<int>();
        public List<int> Winners {
            get {
                return winners;
            }
        }

        public Rank() {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is a higher level algoritm method which will eventually check who is the winner
        /// </summary>
        public void DetermineWinner() {
            for (int i = 0; i < Deal.NumberOfPlayers; i++) {
                firstValue = 0;
                secondValue = 0;
                thirdValue = 0;
                flushCounter = 1;
                straightCounter = 1;
                firstConsequtiveNum = 1;
                secondConsequtiveNum = 1;
                thirdConsequtiveNum = 1;


                royalFlush = false;
                straightFlush = false;
                straight = false;
                flush = false;
                nextPair = false;
                finalPair = false;
                twoPair = false;
                pair = false;
                threeKind = false;
                fourKind = false;
                fullHouse = false;
                Deal.SortDeckByValue(Deal.Players[i]);
                Deal.SortDeckBySuit(Deal.Players[i]);

                CheckIfFlush(Deal.Players[i]);

                CheckForValue(Deal.Players[i]);

                CheckForOutcome(Deal.Players[i]);
            }
            CheckForWinner();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method will check if the player's card has a flush
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="who">The player</param>
        private void CheckIfFlush(Player who) {
            for (int j = 0; j < who.SuitSortedHand.Count - 1; j++) {
                if (who.SuitSortedHand[j].SuitValue == who.SuitSortedHand[j + 1].SuitValue) {
                    flushCounter++;
                } else {
                    flushCounter = 1;
                } if (flushCounter == 5) {
                    flush = true;
                }
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This method will check if the player's card has any
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="who"></param>
        private void CheckForValue(Player who) {
            int highCardIndex = who.ValueSortedHand.Count - 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < who.ValueSortedHand.Count - 1; j++) {
                if ((who.ValueSortedHand[j].FaceValue + 10) == who.ValueSortedHand[j + 1].FaceValue) {
                    straightCounter++;
                    if (straightCounter == 5) {
                        who.HandRank[1] = who.ValueSortedHand[j + 1].FaceValue;
                        if (flushCounter == 5 && who.HandRank[1] == 140) {
                            royalFlush = true;
                        } else if (flushCounter == 5) {
                            straightFlush = true;
                        } else {
                            straight = true;
                        }
                    }
                    SortPairs(who);

                } else if (who.ValueSortedHand[j].FaceValue != who.ValueSortedHand[j + 1].FaceValue) {
                    straightCounter = 1;
                    SortPairs(who);

                } else if (who.ValueSortedHand[j].FaceValue == who.ValueSortedHand[j + 1].FaceValue) {
                    straightCounter = 1;
                    if (!nextPair) {
                        firstConsequtiveNum++;
                        firstValue = who.ValueSortedHand[j].FaceValue;
                    } else if (nextPair && !finalPair) {
                        secondConsequtiveNum++;
                        secondValue = who.ValueSortedHand[j].FaceValue;
                    } else if (finalPair) {
                        thirdConsequtiveNum++;
                        thirdValue = who.ValueSortedHand[j].FaceValue;
                    }
                } if (j == who.ValueSortedHand.Count - 2) {

                    SortPairs(who);
                    CheckIfConsequtive();
                    do {
                        highCard = true;
                        if (secondConsequtiveNum == 1) {
                            who.HandRank[2] = who.ValueSortedHand[j + 1].FaceValue;
                            if (who.HandRank[1] == who.HandRank[2]) {
                                highCardIndex--;
                                highCard = false;
                            }
                        }
                    } while (!highCard);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method will sort out any consequtive cards (i.e. pairs) to be evaluated later
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="who"></param>
        private void SortPairs(Player who) {
            int temp;
            if (firstConsequtiveNum > 1 && !nextPair) {
                nextPair = true;
                who.HandRank[1] = firstValue;
            } else if (secondConsequtiveNum > 1 && !finalPair) {
                finalPair = true;
                if (secondConsequtiveNum > firstConsequtiveNum) {
                    temp = firstConsequtiveNum;
                    who.HandRank[2] = who.HandRank[1];
                    who.HandRank[1] = secondValue;
                    firstConsequtiveNum = secondConsequtiveNum;
                    secondConsequtiveNum = temp;
                } else if (secondValue > firstValue) {
                    who.HandRank[2] = who.HandRank[1];
                    who.HandRank[1] = secondValue;
                    firstConsequtiveNum = secondConsequtiveNum;
                } else {
                    who.HandRank[2] = secondValue;
                }
            } else if (thirdConsequtiveNum > 1) {
                if (thirdConsequtiveNum > firstConsequtiveNum) {
                    temp = firstConsequtiveNum;
                    who.HandRank[2] = who.HandRank[1];
                    who.HandRank[1] = firstValue;
                    firstConsequtiveNum = thirdConsequtiveNum;
                    secondConsequtiveNum = temp;
                } else if (thirdConsequtiveNum == firstConsequtiveNum) {
                    if (thirdValue > firstValue) {
                        who.HandRank[2] = who.HandRank[1];
                        who.HandRank[1] = thirdValue;
                    } else if (thirdValue > secondValue) {
                        who.HandRank[2] = thirdValue;
                        secondConsequtiveNum = thirdConsequtiveNum;
                    }
                } else if (thirdConsequtiveNum == secondConsequtiveNum) {
                    if (thirdValue > secondValue) {
                        who.HandRank[2] = thirdValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method will check if there is any consequtive cards and determine their ranks.
        /// </summary>
        private void CheckIfConsequtive() {
            if (firstConsequtiveNum == 4) {
                fourKind = true;
            } else if (firstConsequtiveNum == 3 && secondConsequtiveNum == 2) {
                fullHouse = true;
            } else if (firstConsequtiveNum == 3) {
                threeKind = true;
            } else if (firstConsequtiveNum == 2 && secondConsequtiveNum == 2) {
                twoPair = true;
            } else if (firstConsequtiveNum == 2) {
                pair = true;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This method will check what the player has in terms of hand rank
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="who"></param>
        private void CheckForOutcome(Player who) {
            if (royalFlush) { // if royal flush
                who.HandRank[0] = 9;
            } else if (straightFlush) { // if straight flush
                who.HandRank[0] = 8;
            } else if (fourKind) { // if four of a kind
                who.HandRank[0] = 7;
            } else if (fullHouse) { // if full house
                who.HandRank[0] = 6;
            } else if (flush) { // if flush
                who.HandRank[0] = 5;
            } else if (straight) { // if straight
                who.HandRank[0] = 4;
            } else if (threeKind) { // if three of a kind
                who.HandRank[0] = 3;
            } else if (twoPair) { // if two pair
                who.HandRank[0] = 2;
            } else if (pair) { // if pair
                who.HandRank[0] = 1;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This method will check who is the winner
        /// </summary>
        private void CheckForWinner() {
            //Work in progress
            int BestHand = -1;
            int HighCard = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < Deal.NumberOfPlayers; i++) {
                if (Deal.Players[i].HandRank[0] > BestHand) {
                    winners.Clear();
                    BestHand = Deal.Players[i].HandRank[0];
                    HighCard = Deal.Players[i].HandRank[2];
                    winners.Add(i);
                } else if (Deal.Players[i].HandRank[0] == BestHand) {
                    if (Deal.Players[i].HandRank[2] == HighCard) {
                        winners.Add(i);
                    } else if (Deal.Players[i].HandRank[2] > HighCard) {
                        winners.Clear();
                        BestHand = Deal.Players[i].HandRank[0];
                        HighCard = Deal.Players[i].HandRank[2];
                        winners.Add(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public string PlayerHandRank(int rank) {
            string rankName = "";
            switch (rank) {
                case 9:
                    rankName = "Royal Flush";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    rankName = "Straight Flush";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    rankName = "Four of a Kind";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    rankName = "Full House";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    rankName = "Flush";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    rankName = "Straight";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rankName = "Three of a Kind";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    rankName = "Two Pair";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    rankName = "Pair";
                    break;
                case 0:
                    rankName = "High Card";
                    break;
            }
            return rankName;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger a few times until this happens?  That would most likely show you why it's not always being called.

Comment: Do you have any exceptions in the output window?

Comment: Is it possible `rank.Winners.Count` to be 0?

Comment: I tried debugging a few times but they just so happen to be the times where it did call them and (I know I will sound lazy) it takes a lot of time to do the method before Winning() as it is checking all the cards to see if they (for example) have a flush, etc.

Comment: rank.Winners.Count won't be 0 as the first player will automatically fill rank.Winners.

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat how would you do that?

Comment: The only reason `Winner` would not be called is if your program isn't completing - either because of logic you've not shown us or, more likely, because of an exception.  Debug with "Break on all exceptions" enabled and see where your error is.

Comment: I do feel that it may be something in Rank but I can't figure out how it would break.

I've added the rank class to my question. Note that ValueSortedHand sorts the cards by value and SuitSortedHand sorts the cards by suit value.

Comment: Also, I am sure you're just starting out and I don't want to knock you but you don't want all your methods to be `static` and might be a good time to investigate some patterns / best practices before you get too involved.

Comment: @Belogix It is just meant to be a test program. I am new though and only know for some reason that static methods work in the main method for some reason (or class methods). I could be totally wrong and there is some mysterious way that people do it.

Comment: Way too much code. Better describe what output and debug results you get and why you think the method isn't being called.

Comment: I am such an idiot everyone. There was an infinite loop which I didn't set the value correctly.

Comment: +1 for Self-deprecation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one way `Winner` isn't getting called - the program is stopping execution before getting there because of an exception. Modify you're code in `Main` to this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    try
    {
        SetPlayers();
        WriteCards();
        SeeWhoWins();
        Winner();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

and that will give you all the detail you need to further begin debugging your program. You'll get a line number and everything.

Comment: Thank you for showing me that, it turns out that I forgot to change one of the variables in the program to prevent an infinite loop from happening but thanks to you, the problem is solved.

Comment: @Brian, I'm glad I could be of assistance!